# Uncaught ReferenceError:some_string is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

In controller class, I have added

```
model.addObject("hostname", hostname);
```

and tried to catch it in my jsp page with

```
var hostname=<%=request.getAttribute("hostname")%> ;
```

Yet, this is throwing error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError:**some_string** is not defined
```

What can be done to avoid this?

Comment: Does `<%=request.getAttribute("hostname")%> ;` produce the text `some_string` rather than the string literal `"some_string"`? If so, the former is going to be read as a variable which doesn't exist. The latter is just a normal string.

Comment: @VLAZ...it will be just **some_string** rather than **"some_string"**

Comment: There is your problem - you're generating invalid code that then gets executed and produces an error.

Comment: How to avoid  that invalid code?

Comment: Generate the code so it's a valid string. Likely `"<%=request.getAttribute("hostname")%>"` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: You are not passing a variable from one program to another, you are programmatically generating JavaScript source code from JSP.

`some_string` is a *variable name*, but not one you've declared, so you get a ReferenceError.

You need to generate the JS source code which gives you the result you need.

For most cases, due to the compatibility between JS and JSON, you can use a JSON stringifier to generate the source code that creates your values (this is a good generic solution as it will do The Right Thing with quotes, new lines, arrays, etc).

Be careful as if the string contains `</script>` you need to escape the `/` to prevent it terminating the `<script>` element. Some JSON serializers will do this by default. I don't know if Java's will.